# VM connected to network but not to internet in VMware Player 6 on Windows 8.1 host

Tags: ubuntu, networking, virtual-machine, vmware-player

So I am running Bitnami's MEAN stack in VMware Player 6.0.2 on Windows 8.1 and the VM connects just fine to the network:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/xfdzohjuuepz52w/ifconfig.PNG

However, I am having a great deal of trouble getting the VM to communicate with the internet. No matter what sort of action I take (even something as simple as `apt-get update`), the machine just sits there and eventually fails to connect.

Here is my VM's Network Adapter configuration:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/37106530/Network%20Adapter.PNG

On my host Windows 8.1 computer, I actually have the `VMware Bridge Protocol` enabled but for VMware Network Adapters (VMnet1 and VMnet 8), but they are listed as having `No Internet access` in my Network and Sharing Center. I am not entirely sure if these adapters are relevant to connecting the VM to the internet, to be honest.

This is the first time I have ever had an issue connecting a virtual machine to the internet. This problem is also happening with other VM's I am trying to run.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong and how I can fix it?

Comment: Have you tried disabling the firewall in Windows to see if it is blocking the traffic?  Also in VMWare player what is your network configuration?  NAT or Bridged?

Comment: It's bridged. Sorry, I put in the wrong image for the adapter. It's been updated.

Comment: Did you try disabling Windows Firewall on the host?